# How is this image created, is it an action or a plug-in?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Please, help to figure out the technique!)

[image]

Comment: How certain are you it was done in Photoshop? It looks like the kind of thing [StudioArtist](https://synthetik.com) would be good at.

Answer (score 2):

**Warning! Rough attempt!**

I'm posting this awful (5 mins effort) piece of work because I think it illustrates the main concepts of how the effect was achieved, and also because I found the original photo which I thought would interest you, or anyone else having a go.

Of course this could also be one filter/action that I have not encountered. But here is how I did it:

1. Apply a shed load of grain
2. Play with levels to achieve contrast
3. The purple actually started to appear on it's own, which was interesting
4. Apply a texture which I cannot find, so instead I used some diagonal solid lines - just for illustrative purposes - which I at least broke apart a little with the "graphic pen" filter (it's been a while since I was in the filter gallery!)
5. Apply a layer mask to the texture pattern and softly remove from face
6. The "false" colouring I could not crack. I suspect it's some kind of separate shadow, mid, highlight boosting, but could not replicate it (in five minutes ;) so I painted the pink onto a new layer and blended it.

I hope that helps somewhat. Original and my awful attempt below...

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for your investigation! Several secrets revealed, really interesting about the self-appeared purple.

Comment: My pleasure, you can mark correct if it helped :)